# How can I call for API data from a component

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have an application that searches for countries and displays more information about the country after the search result only contains one country or if the user selects to show more about that country. I want to call an API to show the weather for the capital of that country. I want to add it inside my component which does so. I already have an API call for countries, how can I get my weather API calls to function from a component after it is loaded?

```
const App = () => {
const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
const [searchName, setSearchName] = useState("");
const [capital, setCapital] = useState("");
const [weather, setWeather] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
 axios
   .get(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/${searchName}`)
   .then(response => {
     console.log(`>> Response: ${JSON.stringify(response)}`);

     setCountries(response.data);
   });
}, [searchName]);

 const handleSearch = event => {
  setSearchName(event.target.value);
  };
  const Country = ({ capital, name, population, languages, flag }) => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  return (
   <div>
      <p>
        {name}{" "}
       <button props={countries} onClick={() => setShow(!show)}>
        {show ? "hide" : "show"}>
       </button>
       {show && ( // use show flag to conditionally render country info
         <SingleCountry
           name={name}
           capital={capital}
           population={population}
           languages={languages}
           flag={flag}
         />
       )}
     </p>
   </div>
   );
 };

const SingleCountry = ({ name, capital, population, languages, flag }) => 
 {
return (
  <div>
    <h3>{name}</h3>
    <p>capital {capital}</p>
    <p>population {population}</p>
    <h2>languages</h2>
    <ul>
      {languages.map(el => (
        <li>{el.name}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
    <img src={flag} alt="OOPS" class="flag-image" />
    {useEffect(() => {
      axios
        .get(
          `https://api.weatherstack.com/current? 
 ebff312fa5277278461024b26999308a&${capital}`
        )
        .then(response => {
          const apiResponse = response.data;
          console.log(
            `Current temparture in ${apiResponse.location.name} is 
${apiResponse.current.temperature}℃`
          );
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    })}
  </div>
 );
 };
 const Countries = () => {
  if (countries.length === 0) {
   return <span class="results__label"> Search something </span>;
 }
  if (countries.length === 1) {
   setCapital(countries.map(c => c.capital));
   console.log(capital);
   return countries.map(c => (
    <SingleCountry
      name={c.name}
      capital={c.capital}
      population={c.population}
      languages={c.languages}
      flag={c.flag}
    />
   ));
 }

 return (
  <div>
      <span class="results__label"> Search Results: </span>
    <div>
      {countries.map(c => (
        <Country
          name={c.name}
          capital={c.capital}
          population={c.population}
          languages={c.languages}
          flag={c.flag}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  </div>
 );
};

return (
 <div>
   <div style={{ margin: "8px" }}>
     find countries <input onChange={handleSearch} />
   </div>
   <Countries />
   <div />
 </div>
 );
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute the function just after you get the response from the search api, just add a callback to that function after api is resolved.

```
axios.get('apiurl').then((response) => {functioncallback()})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a class component instead of a function component and call the api within the [`ComponentDidMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) lifecycle method, and set the state with the resulting data.